# Dockerfile not being found for Google cloud run

Tags: python, django, docker, dockerfile, google-cloud-run

I've hit another bug. I'm now trying to set up continuous deployment for Google Cloud Run from my GitHub, and it's not finding my Dockerfile. I've tried various combinations with my file paths, but it still gives me the

```
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /workspace/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
```

error.

[This is my file structure from VSCode, and if I run the command from the first Exeplore folder, it finds the Dockerfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJz09.png)

The source directory is public, so I just can't figure out why it's not finding the Dockerfile.

https://github.com/Pierre-siddall/exeplore

Any advice at all would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

EDIT 1:

For some reason, the file path had some capitalisation that was different than what was on my VSCode - I suspect something on Github's end. Now I'm having issues getting the continuous deployment to actually update the page, but it is redeploying, but not updating now.

Comment: Your docker is in subfolder. Can you share your trigger configuration?

Comment: Issue I believe was on Github's formatting end - I had to change the . to ./ExePlore instead. No clue why. Now it's deploying, but not updating, so I'm guessing my yaml is wrong